# Android: Google Fit OAuth Consent Screen is not showing

Tags: android, google-fit

I have integrated Google fit in my app. OAuth consent screen is showing when installing debug build and signed build. But the same is not showing if the app is installed from play store beta. Following code is used for authentication .One doubtful line found on the log cat is below and no other logs found.

> com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.ui.SignInActivity#0](this:0xf47b9000,id:669,api:1,p:32027,c:608)
> disconnect(P): api 1

I have googled a lot and not found any solution. Any one faced such issue? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
private val fitnessOptions: FitnessOptions by lazy {
    FitnessOptions.builder()
        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_WEIGHT, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEIGHT, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
        .build()

GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
    this,
    REQUEST_OAUTH_REQUEST_CODE,
     GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions),
    fitnessOptions
)
```

Comment: need some code sample or more elaborate description of whats in the log

Comment: It seems to be an issue on the Google side not the SDK itself. Does this issue reproduce in older versions of Google Fit? If you still have the debugLog when the issue happened, would be great to share. Also please try replicating the issue quickstart apps. This could also help us pinpoint what's the real cause of your issue.